# SnapshotListener failed to get whereField document after updateData

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I know exactly what is happening but I'm unable to fix it. In my mind this works like:

1. Fetch a document from firestore database where field is a certain string
   `db.collection("Connections").whereField("UID", isEqualTo: user.uid).whereField("status", isEqualTo: "waitingForUser").addSnapshotListener { (querySnap, error) in`
2. I'm storing `let thisStatus: String = data?["status"] as! String` and then I've a switch statement which performs tasks based on what the status is now.
3. If there is a **userID** with status **waitingForUser** I need to update the status to **onGoing**

   `let document = querySnap?.documents.first
     document?.reference.updateData(["status": "onGoing"], completion: { (error) in`

I need snapshot listener because I'll be changing status multiple times.

The problem that I'm having is that it runs successfully for the first time but after step 3 it goes to step 1 and there as the condition is false as the status is no longer **waitingForUser** it's **onGoing** hence making the program to throw fatal error as there is no `data?["status"]`. What should I do to make this work I need listener and I need to change status multiple times.

Here is the **UPDATED** full code block:

```
    db.collection("Connection").whereField("UID2", isEqualTo: user.uid).whereField("status", isEqualTo: "waitingForUser2").addSnapshotListener { (querySnap, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error: \(error)")
        } else {

            let data = querySnap?.documents.first?.data()

            guard let thisStatus: String = data?["status"] as! String 
            else { return }

            switch thisStatus {
            case "waitingForUser2":
                //Update the status to onGoing
                let document = querySnap?.documents.first

                document?.reference.updateData([
                                "status": "onGoing"
                                ], completion: { (error) in

                                    print("Status is now on going")
                })

            case "connectionMade":
                print("it's connection made")
            default:
                print("DEFAULT is ON")
            }
        }
```

Comment: There's something else wrong as as changing the status field from `status: waitingForUser` to `status: onGoing` will not cause an error. Even if you delete the status field, it will not cause a fatal error. This is the reason this site guide says to 'include code in your question'. Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please update your question and we'll take a look!

Comment: Oh. And this code is dangerous `querySnap?.documents.first` as you are force unwrapping an optional and if it's nil *that will cause a fatal error*. When you force unwrap, you are guaranteeing it will not be nil. You need to check that optional for nil before working with it.

Comment: @Jay thank you for your comments I've added the full code block. I understand doing `querySnap?.documents.first` is dangerous but there will always be just one document in this collection. It might sound weird but this is how things are happening for this functionality. So since there will be just one document for which the status will change and based on which the switch statement will perform different functionalities as long as the listener is on.

Comment: @Jay nothing is being force unwrapped there.

Comment: @Fogmeister My apologies - poor choice of words and meaning. The point was that querySnap is an optional and may be nil. If it is, then *let thisStatus: String = data?["status"] as! String* will definitely crash with a `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION`. So it would be better to use `guard` or `if let` to work with that var to prevent a crash in nil cases.

Comment: @Jay ah ok. Yeah. That definitely is dangerous. I didn’t spot the forced cast. 

Comment: Thanks for updating the code. The issue is the same as I mentioned in my first comment. The query may or may not return data, so whatever fields are listening on or their values will not cause a fatal error. What *will* cause a fatal error is in how a snapshot is handled with there is NO data. The crash is because you are telling the code there will be data returned, guaranteed not to be nil - that is not the case. If there are no documents that have a matching user id and the status of waitingForUser2, it's going to return nothing in the snapshot. You need to account for those cases.